# Attempting to launch a php scrip in the background from a php script, using the exec() function, on a raspberry pi

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

I want to have a chat bot working on my raspberry pi.

In the command line, I am entering this command:

```
nohup php /path/to/script.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

And this works. When I decide I need the the bot to be down, I enter this command:

```
killall php
```

This works, but I want to be able to start and stop the script from a browser.

So, in my dashboard php script....

```
//This command works.
$runningProc = exec("pgrep -a php");


//This command does not. The process starts, but immediately ends
$startCommand = "nohup php /path/to/script.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &";
exec($startCommand);

//This command does not seem to work for a nohup started from the command line. 
exec("killall php");
```

---

Okay, so I figured out what was going on, once I found some relevant logs.

In my dashboard file I changed the exec() argument to :

```
$startCommand = "nohup php script.php >/dev/null 2> nohup.out &";
exec($startCommand);
```

This way, I could review the 'nohup.out' file for any errors.

The first require() command triggered a "No such file" error. Changing that function to the full filepath made everything work as expected.